# I'm not sure about the use of "great nature" and "reinforced concrete buildings" in this composition

Tags: word-usage

This is a student's composition, I'm not sure about the use of "great nature" and "reinforced concrete buildings" in this composition, are they being used properly here? (Any proofreading comments will be much appreciated.)

> Campus is a place for us to study.
>
> **It's environment ought to combine itself with the great Nature other than those reinforced concrete buildings now we see.**
>
> So greening our campus is rather important. There should be various plants in our schools. There should be flowers in different seasons.
>
> Let's try to make the schools ever green throughout the year. The plants are beneficial to children's body and mind. They will help to create a better campus environment for us.

Comment: I would use "rather" instead of "other" to indicate opposites. Also "Nature" is not normally capitalized, unless revered as in some cultures or religions.

Comment: Needs "Its" instead of "It's" in the beginning.  I'd also move "now" to the end.

Comment: Capitalizing nature could be wrong, or it could be a clever way to personify nature as the psudeo-diety that it is commonly revered as, without sidetracking the thought. After all, didn't the Greeks sort of do the same thing with Gaia?

Comment: Not every student essay demonstrates facility with the English language. If this is an essay by a seventh grader, its errors are excusable. If this is an essay by a freshman in college, I'd recommend remedial English. I used to ask for writing samples from job applicants. I'd never hire an adult who purported to be college-educated and yet wrote such drivel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the student just wanted to convey a message that the campus needs more greenery. What he meant by "great nature" is just nature, in its greatness. The "Reinforced concrete buildings" implies the buildings that are present in the campus. To understand the context, you can omit "great" in *"great nature"* and "
reinforced concrete" in *"reinforced concrete buildings"*. What he meant is :

> The campus is a place for them to study. The campus should have more greenery around it. It needs to be a perfect combination of nature and man-made structures, which at present lacks trees and plants. He wants the campus to be filled with flowering plants and wants too see the campus maintain its greenery throughout the year. The impact of the plants are also explained by the student.